# How to find sum of infinite geometric series without n=1?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I understand how to find the sum of an infinite geometric series with an **n=1**

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(r)^{n-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}$

However, for sums with N **not** beginning at 1 (for example, 5 or something else) I was wondering if there was an elegant way to find this sum. I have attempted to subtract the first few terms to no avail. Of course, this assumes that my |r| < 1.

Comment: The sum is the first term of the series divided by $1-r$.

Comment: Why has subtraction failed?

Comment: why the $a_0?$ also you need to say $|r|<1.$

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for the sum of the series is

$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty r^n = \frac{r^N}{1-r}
$$

which can be derived from the one you wrote and the fact that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^N r^n = \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}
$$
which can be proved by induction. Notice that this last formula holds regardless of $r$ (in particular, it holds also for $|r|> 1$).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the summation at the $i$'th term $a_i$, use the summation formula starting at that term; use $a' = ar^{i - 1}$, then calculate $\frac{a'}{1 - r}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract out the partial sum of the first $m$ terms:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a r^j = a\frac{1-r^m}{1-r}$$

So the infinite sum without terms $0,1,2,...,m-1$ is:

$$\sum_{j=m}^{\infty} a r^j = \left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a r^j\right] - \left[\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a r^j\right] = \frac{a}{1-r} - a\frac{1-r^m}{1-r} = \frac{a r^m}{1-r}.$$

Comment: This answer has the form most like the problem I am dealing with. Elementary, but with ar = (1/3^n) I cannot seem to get an answer using the form ((ar^m)/1-r)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k = a}^b x^k = \frac{x^a - x^{b+1}}{1-x}$$

$$\sum_{k = a}^{+\infty} x^k = \frac{x^a}{1-x}$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^b x^k = \frac{x^{1-b}-1}{x-1}$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Provided $|x| < 1$

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a converging series it holds that : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=(a_1+a_2+...+a_{k-1})+\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_n$$
So, 
$$\frac{a}{1-r}=a+ar+ar^2+..+ar^k+\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a\\$$ $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a=\frac{a}{1-r}-a\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}=\frac{ar^{k+1}}{1-r}$$