# Find the PMF of $X-Y$ given the density $f(k)=1_{\mathbb N_0}(k) p^k (1-p)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find the probability mass funcion of $X-Y$ given $X,Y$ are independent random variables and their PMF is given by: $$f(k)=1_{\mathbb N_0}(k) p^k (1-p)$$
where $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $1_{\mathbb N_0}(k)$ is the indicator function.

**What I have tried so far:**

Define $Z=X-Y$ Then $P(Z=z)=P(X=x,Y=x-z)$. Using the convoltuion formlula:

$$\begin{align} p_Z(z)& =\sum_kp^k(1-p)p^{k-z}(1-p) \\ &= (1-p)^2p^{-z}\sum_{k=?} p^{2k}\end{align} $$

My problem is that I am not sure where my summation index starts. For example, Let's say I want to know $P(Z=3)=p_Z(3)$.Starting my sum at $k=1$ would mean that for one of the terms I have $$P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=-2)$$However, my PMF is not defined for negative numbers. Is there a compact way to write the summation that excludes these cases where the random variable $Y$ takes on negative values?

Comment: Observe that $P(X=x,Y=x-z)$ only takes positive values if $x\geq0$ and $x-z\geq0$, or equivalently if $x\geq\max\{0,z\}$. So that is where index $k$ should start. I think it is good to observe two separate cases: $z<0$ (so that $\max\{0,z\}=0$) and $z\geq0$ (so that $\max\{0,z\}=z$).

Comment: @drhab  I was thinking of splitting it into cases but I made an error. This way makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Re: "However, my PMF is not defined for negative numbers." @Nullspace  It *is* defined ... as $0$ when the argument is not in the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the common pmf of $X$ and $Y$ is

$$P(X=k)=pq^k \mathbf1_{\{0,1,\ldots\}}(k)\qquad,\,0<p=1-q<1$$

Note that support of $Z=X-Y$ is the set of integers $\mathbb Z$.

Then,

\begin{align}
P(Z=z)&=\sum_k P\left(X=k, Y=k-z\right)
\\&=\sum_k P(X=k)P(Y=k-z)
\\&=p^2\sum _k q^k\mathbf1_{\{0,1,\ldots\}}(k)\cdot q^{k-z}\mathbf1_{\{z,z+1,\ldots\}}(k)
\\&=p^2\sum_{k=m}^\infty q^{2k-z}\,\mathbf1_{\mathbb Z}(z)\qquad,\, m=\max\{0,z\}
\end{align}

This is a familiar infinite geometric series, from which it follows that

$$P(Z=z)=\frac{pq^{2m-z}}{1+q}\mathbf1_{\mathbb Z}(z)$$

If you consider the cases $z\ge 0$ and $z<0$ separately, then you can write this without using $m$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Quick question: Shouldn't de denominator be $1-q$. Looking at the closed form solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693584/how-to-find-sum-of-infinite-geometric-series-without-n-1/1693590#1693590 There seems to be a minus in the denominator. Or am I missing something?

Comment: From $\sum_{k=m}^\infty q^{2k}=q^{2m}(1+q^2+q^4+\cdots)$, you can see the common ratio is $q^2$. So the denominator becomes $1-q^2=(1+q)(1-q)=p(1+q)$. BTW, I realised after answering that the $p$ in your question is my $q$.

Comment: Ah I think I know why I got confused. So in "my notation" the final form is: 

$$P(Z=z)=\frac{(1-p)p^{2m-z}}{1+p} \mathbf 1_{\mathbb Z}(z)$$

since the relations are $p=q$ and $(1-p)=q$ correct?

Comment: Right. $\color\white{.}$

Comment: Also @Nullspace: $2\max\{0,z\}-z = \lvert z\rvert$ .

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative visual approach, to calculate

$$P(Z=z)=P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=k-z)$$

the following drawing will help (it helped me a lot!)

[image]

Thus when $z\geq 0$ the resulting series is

$$P(Z=z)=p^2\sum_{x=z}^{\infty}q^x\cdot q^{x-z}=\frac{p^2q^z}{1-q^2}=\frac{pq^z}{1+q}$$

When $z<0$ the resulting series is

$$P(Z=z)=p^2\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}q^x\cdot q^{x-z}=\frac{p^2q^{-z}}{1-q^2}=\frac{pq^{-z}}{1+q}$$

Concluding, the resulting pmf is

$$P(Z=z)=\frac{pq^{|z|}}{1+q}$$

Here is the resulting pmf with $p=0.5$

[image]